# How do I call the exact function on page load?

Tags: javascript, html, function

I am coding a website and I found this cool effects (https://github.com/codrops/SegmentEffect/) on GitHub and I was wondering, how could I make the image and the text appear exactly like that without having to press the "Show effect" button. I am wondering more specifically for the "index5.html" page.

I tried this code on the <script> section of "index5.html" and I managed to load the function without the need of the "Show effect" button, but the distortion effect is not working for some reason

```
<script>
    (function() {
        var headline = document.querySelector('.trigger-headline'),
            segmenter = new Segmenter(document.querySelector('.segmenter'), {
                pieces: 8,
                positions: [
                    {top: 0, left: 0, width: 100, height: 100},
                    {top: 0, left: 0, width: 100, height: 100},
                    {top: 0, left: 0, width: 100, height: 100},
                    {top: 0, left: 0, width: 100, height: 100},
                    {top: 0, left: 0, width: 100, height: 100},
                    {top: 0, left: 0, width: 100, height: 100},
                    {top: 0, left: 0, width: 100, height: 100},
                    {top: 0, left: 0, width: 100, height: 100},
                    {top: 0, left: 0, width: 100, height: 100}
                ],
                shadows: false,
                parallax: true,
                parallaxMovement: {min: 10, max: 30},
                animation: {
                    duration: 2500,
                    easing: 'easeOutExpo',
                    delay: 0,
                    opacity: .1,
                    translateZ: {min: 10, max: 25}
                },
                onReady: function() {
                    headline.classList.remove('trigger-headline--hidden');
                }
            });
        segmenter.animate();
    })();
    </script>
```

I hope someone can help me, it seems pretty easy for someone experienced, but I don't really have the knowledge to understand all the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming you want it to trigger the effect as soon as the page loads?

If so, you just need to replace the following code (in the index.html file from the github the github repository you posted):

```
<script>
    (function() {
        var headline = document.querySelector('.trigger-headline'),
            trigger = document.querySelector('.btn--trigger'),
            segmenter = new Segmenter(document.querySelector('.segmenter'), {
                onReady: function() {
                    trigger.classList.remove('btn--hidden');
                    trigger.addEventListener('click', function() {
                        segmenter.animate();
                        headline.classList.remove('trigger-headline--hidden');
                        this.classList.add('btn--hidden');
                    });
                }
            });
    })();
    </script>
```

With this code:

```
<script>
    (function () {
        var headline = document.querySelector('.trigger-headline'),
            trigger = document.querySelector('.btn--trigger'),
            segmenter = new Segmenter(document.querySelector('.segmenter'), {
                onReady: function () {
                    segmenter.animate();
                    headline.classList.remove('trigger-headline--hidden');
                    this.classList.add('btn--hidden');
                }
            });
    })();
</script>
```

You'll also want to be sure to include all of the js/css dependencies required in the index.html file or it won't work.